# How to return new points and new faces when cut a mesh with plane using clip?

Tags: c++, cgal

I have known that I can cut a closed mesh with plane using clip function as follow:

```
Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/clip.h
template <class TriangleMesh, class Plane_3>
void clip(TriangleMesh& tm, const Plane_3& plane, bool close);
```

And I can get a return closed mesh, but I also want to get the new faces and new points added by clip function, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use internal funtions. They are left undocumented for a reason. Furthermore, this particular function exists in a documented form since the version 4.13, that's the one you should use.

If you look at [the doc](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga5bf228a516a46f6d1c80937067a17f7e), you can see a named parameter called `visitor`. That is what you need.

If you now look at [the concept of the visitor](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13.2/Polygon_mesh_processing/classPMPCorefinementVisitor.html#a6e67ca5495678a470e53498b451ce52f), you see the functions that you can override. I think the one you are looking for is [this one](https://doc.cgal.org/4.13.2/Polygon_mesh_processing/classPMPCorefinementVisitor.html#a51a2222bdcadf27fecfd8c3862300d0b).
You can look at [this example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/releases/CGAL-4.14.3/Polygon_mesh_processing/examples/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement_mesh_union_with_attributes.cpp) to see how to use it.